# Pointers, counter gets confused

Tags: c, pointers, counter

I am trying to write a program that finds how many banknotes are required to pay workers salary. After each worker, it should show how many banknotes that worker get, and which banknotes. And when there isn't any worker left, it should show how many banknotes of all workers get. So far so good.

But here is the thing: Whenever a worker gets 20 TL (Turkish Lira), it counts that bill as 50 TL. But at the and of the program, when writing how many banknotes at all, program counts that 20 bills as 20 bills instead of 50. You will understand what I mean at the image. That 7 numbers represent 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, and 1 TL bills. All other banknote counters works normal. But program thinks 20 TL's are 50TL. Even though program shows correct numbers at the end.

[image]

As you can see 4th worker gets 20TL but is says at the next line "give him a 50TL banknote", just like 9th worker. Other workers' banknotes and total banknote count is correct despite the fact that it shows 20TL banknotes as 50TL

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void banknot(int, int *, int *, int *, int *, int *, int *, int *);

int ikiyuztl_top=0,yuztl_top=0,ellitl_top=0,yirmitl_top=0,ontl_top=0,bestl_top=0;
int birtl_top=0;

int main()
{
int i, personel, tam;
double maas;
int ikiyuztl=0,yuztl=0,ellitl=0,yirmitl=0,ontl=0,bestl=0;
int birtl=0;

int *ikiyuztl_ptr, *yuztl_ptr, *ellitl_ptr, *yirmitl_ptr, *ontl_ptr, *bestl_ptr;
int *birtl_ptr;

ikiyuztl_ptr=&ikiyuztl;
yuztl_ptr=&yuztl;
ellitl_ptr=&ellitl;
yirmitl_ptr=&ellitl;
ontl_ptr=&ontl;
bestl_ptr=&bestl;
birtl_ptr=&birtl;

printf("Personel sayisini giriniz:\n"); /* It means "How many workers are there?" */
scanf("%d",&personel);

for (i=1; i<=personel; i++) {
    printf("%d. personelin maasini TL cinsinden giriniz\n",i); /*Write salary*/
    scanf("%lf",&maas);

    tam=maas;

    banknot(tam,ikiyuztl_ptr,yuztl_ptr,ellitl_ptr,yirmitl_ptr,ontl_ptr,bestl_ptr,birtl_ptr);

    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",ikiyuztl,yuztl,ellitl,yirmitl,ontl,bestl,birtl);

}

printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n",ikiyuztl_top,yuztl_top,ellitl_top,yirmitl_top,ontl_top,bestl_top,birtl_top);

return 0;

}

void banknot(int tam, int *ikiyuztl, int *yuztl, int *ellitl, int *yirmitl, int *ontl, int *bestl, int *birtl)
{
*ikiyuztl=0;
*yuztl=0;
*ellitl=0;
*yirmitl=0;
*ontl=0;
*bestl=0;
*birtl=0;

while (tam>=200) {
    *ikiyuztl = *ikiyuztl + 1;
    ikiyuztl_top++;
    tam=tam-200;
}

while (tam>=100) {
    *yuztl = *yuztl + 1;
    yuztl_top++;
    tam=tam-100;
}

while (tam>=50) {
    *ellitl = *ellitl + 1;
    ellitl_top++;
    tam=tam-50;
}

while (tam>=20) {
    *yirmitl = *yirmitl + 1;
    yirmitl_top++;
    tam=tam-20;
}

while (tam>=10) {
    *ontl = *ontl + 1;
    ontl_top++;
    tam=tam-10;
}

while (tam>=5) {
    *bestl = *bestl + 1;
    bestl_top++;
    tam=tam-5;
}

*birtl = tam;
birtl_top = birtl_top+tam;
}
```

Comment: Where does it print how much a worker gets paid?  The only print statements (outside of the prompt for input) just print numbers.

Comment: @ScottHunter Im guessing the pay for each worker is the user input (`scanf("%lf", ...)`), the printed output lists the number of notes per kind of note (200, 100, 50, 20?, ...).

Comment: @ScottHunter
Yes, I am giving program that how much a worker gets (2364 TL for example), it supposed to say to me how many banknotes that worker should get (11 1 1 0 1 0 4 for 2364 TL)

Answer (score 1):

You made a copy & paste mistake at this line:

```
yirmitl_ptr=&ellitl;
```

Thus, the `banknot` function updated the wrong counter variable (`ellitl` instead of `yirmitl`).

It should be:

```
yirmitl_ptr=&yirmitl;
```

**Further notes:**

You don't need all these `*_ptr` variables. Just pass the counters by reference at the `banknot` call:

```
banknot(tam,&ikiyuztl,&yuztl,&ellitl,&yirmitl,&ontl,&bestl,&birtl);
```

Comment: I know but i am supposed to use pointers in this. It is my homework. Thank again.
@matz

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is on line 20:

```
...
yirmitl_ptr=&ellitl;  // Should be yirmitl_ptr=&yirmitl;
...
```

Note that you can save yourself a whole lot of typing if you simply omit these `_ptr` variables and just call your banknot-function like this:

```
banknot(tam, &ikiyuztl, &yuztl, ...)
```